# Deleted entries are not updated in the Listbox control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a `listbox` control in a Windows Form which is used to display the communication response from a connected serial device. When I wish to clear the entries in the `listbox` (called `Listbox1`), I use the following code:

```
Listbox1.Items.Clear();
```

However, it seems that although the above code works perfectly in removing the entries for the first 8 responses, subsequent entries in `Listbox1` are not removable by calling the above code. What is even stranger is that `Listbox1.Items.Count` returns `1` each time a new line of code is entered in `Listbox1`, even though I can see the previous entries in `Listbox1`, so if I try to use `Listbox1.SetSelected(1, true);`, I receive the following error message:

```
InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'
```

This implies that there is only 1 item in `Listbox1` although I can quite clearly see 2 items in `Listbox1`(the supposedly-deleted older entry and the more recent entry).

Please advise on what could be going wrong here. Why are there still entries reflected in `Listbox1` even after calling `Listbox1.Items.Clear()`? How do I erase all entries in `Listbox1` without seeing any stray items left from the previous response?

Comment: Sounds like a possible **multi-threading** issue?  Are you using any threads?  How and when are you updating the ListBox?...and how and when are you reading the number of items in it?

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Yes, I'm calling the update of `Listbox1` from within an async thread (which is a click event handler associated with a button), and `Listbox1` is being updated through a separate thread (which handles the serial comms).

Comment: ...and are the updates/reads being properly invoked to the main UI thread?  How often are you updating the UI?

Comment: Yes, the reads are updated once every 100ms - I've inserted `await Task.Delay(100);` in strategic locations of the code (both before and after calling `Listbox1.Items.Clear()`). I've even tried using `Thread.Sleep(100);` (in place of `await Task.Delay(100);`) but even then the problem remains.

Comment: You could modify your code to wait for the actual response from the device (instead of using a fixed delay that may or may not work) before moving on to the next step in the process.  Would need to see more of your current code to make a suggestion on how to implement this though...

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Are you referring to `await Task.Run(() => { //do something here });`?

Comment: Yes...would need to see a lot more though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - the serial device was requiring a longer time interval to respond to some commands (as opposed to others), hence variable timing had to be used (longer delays for some commands and shorter delays for others). Utilizing similar short delay times (of 100ms) resulted in congestion of the packets received, and caused some entries to be relayed into `Listbox1` even after the `Listbox1.Items.Clear();` command was invoked (& supposedly executed), resulting in stray (supposedly 'deleted') responses to be entered in `Listbox1`.